# How to handle multipart/related data in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, alamofire, multipart

My backend server multipart/related data for images. How to handle it in my iOS client side by using Alamofire?

Answer (score 0):

To upload the multipart image from IOS the sample code is below:

```
 if let URL = try? URLRequest(url: url, method: .post, headers: nil) {
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.001), withName: "file", fileName: params.imageName, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }, with: URL) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                //Enter Success Code
            case .failure:
                //Enter failure Code
            }
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually I know how to upload. But my question is how to download images served as multipart/related by my backend.

Comment: @ZhouHao have you tried using SDWebImage. this is a third party library but this helps in downloading images from url. This also download the image in parts.

Comment: I can't download image from url directly because the backend serve the images as multipart/related data.